# Why macro function isn't call by value?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, call-by-value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define exch(A,B) {int t=A;A=B;B=t;}
int main(void)
{
    int a=1,b=4;
    exch(a,b);
    printf("%d\t%d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:`a=4,b=1`

In the output, a and b have been exchanged; why is a macro not call by value? Please help me by explaining the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because macros are not functions, the preprocessor just replaces the text. After the macro substitution, your program turns into:

```
//code in stdio.h

int main(void)
{
    int a=1,b=4;
    {int t=A;A=B;B=t;}
    printf("%d\t%d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

See? There's no function calls in the swapping.